# Sum with gamma denominator...

Tags: summation, exponential-function, binomial-coefficients, self-learning, gamma-function

I stumbled upon a problem that I'm not sure is stated correctly. They claim the following (without steps):

> $$\sum_{m\geq 3} [4 \cdot \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{ m} + \binom{ \frac{1}{2}} {m-1}]\cdot\frac{x^m}{\Gamma(m - \frac{3}{2})}$$
>   $$=\frac{3e^{-x}(2 - 2e^x + xe^x + x)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$$

Two questions: 1) is it actually possible to simplify this sum as stated? 2) is their answer actually correct?

Comment: Typo?  Maple says it's $$\frac{3 e^{-x}\left(2 - 2 e^x + x e^x + x\right)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$$

Comment: Hint: [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the Gamma function may be useful.

Comment: Thank you, Robert I've edited my answer to the correct solution. Now, in terms of using Euler's reflection formula, I'm not quite sure how that ends up being applicable here (though, it's late, so maybe it'll hit me tomorrow).

Comment: Express $1/2 \choose m$ using Gamma functions and you have a $\Gamma(3/2 - m)$ in the denominator to go with the $\Gamma(m-3/2)$.